# Undefined variable notice in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, undefined

I'm trying to update some records in my database via php. This is the part of my code that returns error:

```
<?php
    //turn on error reporting
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {

     if(isset($title[$i],$descr[$i],$price[$i],$cname[$i],$pid[$i]))
            {
                $query = "
                   UPDATE products
                   SET title='$title[$i]',
                       descr='$descr[$i]',
                       price='$price[$i]',
                       cname='$cname[$i]'
                   WHERE pid='$pid[$i]'
               ";

                $upd = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            }
            else
            {
                $upd = FALSE;
                echo "One of the variables isn't set.\n<br/>";
            }
        }

        if($upd)
        {
            echo "Successful";
            echo "<BR>";
            //display_manager_menu();
        }
        else {
            echo "Something wrong";
        }    
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

It returns: **"Notice: Undefined variable: upd "**. Since I set `$upd` as mysql_query result, I have no idea why I get this message. Any ideas?

Comment: Change `$upd=mysql_query($query);` to `$upd=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and see what's going wrong.

Comment: what is the value of $count ?

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for the instant reply! I tried it but unfortunately it returns the same

Comment: @SoftwareGuy  This is it: $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: @Suspicius: 1. Turn on error reporting. 2. Use `var_dump` everywhere and test if the variables are what you think it is. 3. Indent your code properly. 4. Do not blindly assume that the query executed successfully. 5. Always make sure the variables are set before trying to use them. -- your code should look something like [this](http://pastebin.com/7D8RVbun).

Comment: @AmalMurali Your reply was quite helpful to understand the whole poiont my my query. I followed what you show me and I get a number of these messages "One of the variables isn't set. " and "Something wrong".

Comment: @Suspicius: So, use `var_dump` and try to find out **why** those variables aren't set. I don't see you defining those variables in your current code. Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if($upd){
```

to:

```
if(isset($upd) && $upd){
```

If `$_POST['submit']` isn't set, the variable `$upd` won't be set, either.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue -- rather hides it.

Comment: I got rid of the notice. But my problem exists since when clicking on Submit button I get numerous notices about undefined variables of `title`, `price`, `descr`,`cname`and `pid` in my $query.

Comment: Which means your data is not being posted as no data is being assigned to those variables and therefore they are undefined. Try var_dump($_POST) and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `$udp` is declared within a if-condition. When `$_POST['Submit']` isn’t set, then `$udp` doesn’t get set either.
You can solve this by initializing the variable before the `if(...)`:

```
$udp = false; // initialize $udp before conditional
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $query="UPDATE products SET title='$title[$i]', descr='$descr[$i]', price='$price[$i]', cname='$cname[$i]' WHERE pid='$pid[$i]'";
        $upd=mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

In this case, you initialize `$udp` with `false`, since `mysql_query()` also returns `false` on failure.

Comment: It didn't help. Th problem continues to exist.

Comment: which problem? with the solution above, you should get rid of the `Notice: Undefined variable: upd `..!?

Comment: It only hides the notice, but the $upd is not working properly.

Comment: Then I guess you have a problem with your Mysql-Query!

Answer (score -1):

did you corectly close the php file with the  `?>`  ? i've had this kind of problems solved by simply closing the file correctly.

Comment: I think I did. It hasn't to do with closing the file but with my query or declarations maybe.

Comment: `?>` at the end of a file is optional. -1

Comment: @Suspicius: see my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076502/undefined-variable-notice-in-php-mysql/19076524#comment28199115_19076502).

Comment: Actually, **omitting** the closing tag is considered better (in most cases).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answers of `$upd` only being declared in a conditional, you are writing code as if `register_globals` is on. You should not do this.

Replace `$title` with `$_POST['title']`, `$descr` with `$_POST['descr']` and so on. This is easier done if you concatenate properly:

```
"blah blah blah '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'][$i])." blah blah blah...";
```

Also, sanitize inputs.